# How to get a file name from a list of files using link query

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using linq query to get the filename from a list of file names. but I am getting null value. Is there anything wrong with the code??

```
var folderName = UserDetailsUtil.GetMemberPhotoPathFolderName(SessionData.UserID);
var fileName = SessionData.UserID;
var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Upload/MemberProfilePhotos/" + folderName)));
var actualFileName = fileNames.Where(x => x.StartsWith(fileName)).FirstOrDefault();
```

My image name will be with my userid.  Total images in that particular folder comes into filenames. What i have to do is, I need to get the filename from the list of files

Comment: Side-note: "My image name will be with my userid" then don't use `StartsWith` but `==`, otherwise file `1` and `10` are equal.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your file has an extension, so you need to find it without it, best by using the `Path` class:

```
var actualFileName = fileNames
    .Where(fn => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn) == fileName)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Side-note acc. to "My image name will be with my userid". Then don't use `StartsWith` but `==`, otherwise file `1` and `10` are equal. Changed that already in my code above.